# post-commit hook failed with error code:255 in svn

Tags: svn

When i commit the file

post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output.

My post commit hook for svn is

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

#mailer.py commit "$REPOS" "$REV" /path/to/mailer.conf
/usr/bin/svn update --force /xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx >> /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/logs/repos.log
```

by this error i have to update it manually only.please guide me for proper post commit for auto checkout.advance thanks

Comment: 1. Show content of log 2. Did you hook works as expected, if you run it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

1. Hook must be executable (`chmod +x ...`)
2. You miss shebang string
3. User, under which you running server for managing repository, must have RW rights for `/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx` path
4. If you redirect output of update to STDERR, it will be shown to client